# df.plot.pie plot two pie charts next to each other

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following code that plots two pie charts one below the other. What I want is to plot them next to each other. How do I do that with the below information?

```
    ax1=apr_prev.set_index('Previous').plot.pie(y='Previous_Counts', figsize=(8, 8), title="Top 10 Before", \
        legend=False, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=0, explode=(0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
    ax1.set_ylabel('')
    
    
    ax2=apr_cur.set_index('Current').plot.pie(y='Current_Counts', figsize=(8, 8), title="Top 10 Current", \
        legend=False, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=0, explode=(0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
    ax2.set_ylabel('')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

1. Create 2 axes in the desired layout by:
   `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)`
2. Explictely state for each `pie`, where to plot it by `ax` param. For example:

   ```
   apr_prev.set_index('Previous').plot.pie(y='Previous_Counts', figsize=(8, 8), 
   title="Top 10 Before", legend=False, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=0, 
   explode=(0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), ax=ax1)
   ```